# Installing (Dual-Booting) Windows 10 on a system with Ubuntu 16.04.2 installed (UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

I recently purchased a laptop with Windows 10 on it. I attempted to then install Ubuntu alongside it by taking a USB and using a tool (E.G. Rufus) to burn the necessary Ubuntu installation packages. Long story short, I was able to install Ubuntu, but could not boot into Ubuntu, even following several guides such as changing the Windows bootloader to load the GRUB loader, which all failed to work. I ended up using the "clean" command from Windows DiskPart to delete Windows.

I then installed Ubuntu again, and now have a working version of Ubuntu on my computer. However, I'd like to take a crack at installing Windows 10 alongside it (so this time I'd be installing Windows 10 on Ubuntu as opposed to my first attempt at installing Ubuntu after Windows) and was wondering if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Installing Windows after Ubuntu will very likely result in the loss of the GRUB boot loader.  Far more people are successful doing it in the original order (windows 1st) that you had difficulty with.

Comment: Use an external USB stick to install the Bootloader ?

Comment: You just have to be sure to boot Windows in UEFI mode or it will convert to MBR, in effect erasing Ubuntu. It will make Windows default UEFI boot, but depending on system, you can change that. Just best to make sure you have good backups. And you have to have Windows fast start up off if dual booting. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions. And make sure your Ubuntu installer is ok so you can make the repairs.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of work I confirm that the following method is much easier and yielding for new users of Linux environment. *Warning: Not following these steps correctly can result into Damage to your important files. It is recommended to Make a backup before you proceed. Also make sure you have an internet connection all the time.*

**1. Make space for Windows**

Open GParted and allot at least 20 GB to Windows. But I would recommend 35 GB. Also note the partition name. Example: `sdaX`

**2.Install Windows**

Now install Windows 10 in your new partition that you have just created.

**3.Mount /boot**

If you boot you can observe that your system boots directly to Windows. This is because Windows Boot loader does not recognize Ubuntu. So lets install GRUB.

Load up from your Ubuntu live CD, and then run these commands, Only on of them.(make sure to hit enter after each line)

- If you DO NOT have a separate `/boot` partition:

`sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /mnt
 sudo rm -rf /boot
 sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot`

*`DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE` : replace this with your drive number in step one*

- If you have a SEPARATE `/boot` partition:

`sudo mount /dev/DEVICENAME_FROM_STEP_ONE /boot`

**4.Install the bootloader**

Again in the terminal, run these commands:

`sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
 sudo grub-install /dev/sda

 sudo umount /boot`

*Note that there is no digit after `sda`*

Now just restart, everything should just be fine :).